# Using inherited variables to generate HTML - a cleaner approach?

Tags: php

My website has navigation at the top of the page that is included in all of my pages. Looks something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<? 
 $selected = 'home';
 include('include/header.php'); 
?>
```

The `header.php` file is basically showing the top navigation that is standard on each page.  Above that is a variable that is being inherited by the `header.php` file to "tell" the header file, where the user is, so that the appropriate navigation tab can be selected.

My `header.php` file looks something like:

```
<div id="main_navigation">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PURCHASE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SOMETHING ELSE</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

What I want to do is add HTML to the `<li>` tag to show a css class that will highlight the navigation tab. Is there a more eloquent way to do this besides throwing in this ugly snippit:

```
<div id="main_navigation">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li <? if($selected == 'home'){ print "class = \"select"\"; ?> ><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li <? if($selected == 'about'){ print "class = \"select"\"; ?> ><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li <? if($selected == 'purchase'){ print "class = \"select"\"; ?> ><a href="#">PURCHASE</a></li>
        <li <? if($selected == 'something'){ print "class = \"select"\"; ?> ><a href="#">SOMETHING ELSE</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop and an array:

```
$nav = array( '#' => 'HOME');

echo '<ul id="nav">';
foreach( $nav as $href => $text) {
    $class = ($selected == 'home') ? ' class="select"' : '';
    echo '<li' . $class . '><a href="' . $href . '">' . $text . '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

If all the `href` values really are `#`, then you can omit them in the definition of the array:

```
$nav = array( 'HOME', 'ABOUT US');
```

Then, omit including it in the loop:

```
    echo '<li' . $class . '><a href="#">' . $text . '</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems fairly standard, but you might be able to do it a bit more succintly using the ternary operator:

```
<li class="<?php echo ($selected == 'home') ? 'select' : ''; ?>">
```

But I think that's mostly a matter of style. Even better would be to process these bits outside of the html. And then pass 4 variables to header.php and then write the list like this:

```
<li class="<?php echo $home_class; ?>"> . . .
<li class="<?php echo $about_class; ?>"> . . .
```

etc.

In this way you'd keep all logic out of the html. The biggest gain in this case might be that you can turn the logic into a function that looks something like:

```
function get_menu_item_class($menu_item) {
  if (/* whatever logic to determine if it's selected based on passed parameter */) {
    return 'select';
  }

  return '';
}
```

Then you can just populate the variables fairly easily:

```
$home_class = get_menu_item_class('home');
$about_class = get_menu_item_class('about');
```

etc.

Or maybe forgo the variables altogether and just call the function directly:

```
<li class="<?php echo get_menu_item_class('home'); ?>"> ...
```